# Split cells contents separated by comma using formulas

Tags: excel, formula

I am using Excel 365 and there are items in column A and some cells have a comma as separtor like that

```
Column A
--------
Ahmed
Salem, Ahmed
Reda
Khaled
Salah, Ahmed
```

I have used this formula to split the contents

```
=TRANSPOSE(FILTERXML("<AllText><Num>"&SUBSTITUTE(A2,",","</Num><Num>")&"</Num></AllText>","//Num"))
```

But the results I got are in multiple columns. How can I get all the results in just one column?
The expected result would be in one column

```
Ahmed
Salem
Ahmed
Reda
Khaled
Salah
Ahmed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to join all the cells into a single string, before creating the XML:

```
=FILTERXML("<AllText><Num>"&SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,$A:$A),",","</Num><Num>")&"</Num></AllText>","//Num")
```

- Note `TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,$A:$A)`